# How to implement a scroller in UITableView with only ONE section?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, scrollview

I have lots of data in a UITableView but I don't want any of it in sections. However, I would like to implement a scroller in my table view that works in the same manner as

```
    - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        //...
    }
```

does, but without having sections. I want my scroller to scroll to specific numbers associated with the data in each cell of the table view.

Has anyone done this and can point me in good direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `UITableView` requires at least one section for any cells to be loaded.

Comment: Good comment, changed my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your scroller can get the index of the selected data, you can use [UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]. The code might look something like this:

```
-(void)jumpToSelectedIndex:(NSInteger) selectedIndex {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
}
```